# Get part go text with domDocument in PHP

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument

I've this HTMl coming from a `file_get_contents`:

```
<div class="attractions-attraction-filtered-common-ListingsHeader__listingsCount--PflJ1">
    <span>We found <b>10&nbsp;results</b> for you.</span>
</div>
```

How can I get the number of results (i.e.: 10)?

Note, that the part `PflJ1` is something random.

This is what I tried:

```
$page = file_get_contents($url);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xp = new DOMXpath($dom);

$activitiesNb = $xp->query('//div/span/text()');
$activitiesNb = $activitiesNb->nodeValue;
echo $activitiesNb;
```

But it does not work.

What I'm missing please ?

Thanks.

Comment: perhaps try: `$activitiesNb = $activitiesNb->item(0)->nodeValue;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `evaluate()`:

```
$results = $xp->evaluate('string(//span[contains(., "We found ")]/b/text())');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath needs to be fixed (you're looking for the content of a `b` element). Also, use `item()` in combination with `nodevalue`.

```
<?php
$html = <<<'HTML'
<div class="attractions-attraction-filtered-common-ListingsHeader__listingsCount--PflJ1">
    <span>We found <b>10&nbsp;results</b> for you.</span>
</div>
HTML;
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

$res = $xpath->query('//div[starts-with(@class,"attractions-")]/span/b');
$val = $res ->item(0)->nodeValue;
echo substr($val,0,2)
?>
```

Output : `10`

Alternative :

```
$res = $xpath->evaluate("substring(//div[starts-with(@class,'attractions-')]/span/b,1,2)");
echo $res
```

And if you just have one number (for e.g. 8) :

```
echo substr($val,0,1)
```

or

```
$res = $xpath->evaluate("substring(//div[starts-with(@class,'attractions-')]/span/b,1,1)");
echo $res
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help. How it's work if I have `8&nbsp;results`?

Comment: You mean one digit number ? If that's the case, replace the last value in `substr` (string, start position, length). I've edited my post with an alternative.